# Understanding how a property of type List<> works

Tags: c#, list, properties

I got to think I don't understand how it works.

My specific question is: **Why am I allowed to set the value of a list property element when I have no setter and no backing list variable?**

Let me explain. Let's say I have a CustomerTable class with:

```
public List<string> Name
{
    get
    {
        var names = new List<string>();
        foreach (CustomerRow row in Rows)
        {
            name.Add(row.Name);
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a read-only property show the contents of a column without duplicating data in my class, since I already have a list of rows.

Anyway, my surprise comes when pieces of code like the following one are accepted by Visual Studio without claiming any kind of error (and it even allows me to compile without errors):

```
Name[0] = "John";
```

**I can't understand why this is legal. My property has no set { }, and it doesn't even have a backing list to modify. What is this piece of code supposed to do?**

Shouldn't it work like a method? Is there really a stored list other than the one I generate each time someone "gets" it?

(I can give more details on demand and will also be grateful for any other remarks)

Comment: You should use a `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` instead

Comment: Indeed, that should work as I was expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting the property, rather you are getting the property (which is a list) and then operating on it (in your example, changing its first member). If you were to try:

```
Name = new List<string>();
```

You would get the compilation error you were expecting to get. Note that since you are creating a new list every time, your `Rows` property remains read-only (assuming it is not exposed somewhere else). If you want to make it clear that changes to your returned collection are meaningless, you can change the type of the `Name` property to `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Name
{
    get
    {
        return Rows.Select(row => row.name); //LINQ is more elegant here
    }
}
```

Comment: I would even `return Rows.Select(row => row.name);` which avoids the instanciation of a `List<string>` object and gives and authentic `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Very helpful to understand how it works. Not as I expected. Yet since this list is holding strings and strings work as a value type, this change would not affect my Rows list, would it?

Comment: @Ssithra - I thought about it but didn't want to change the semantics of the original code. If I didn't return a new list, an "evil" consumer could theoretically cast it back to whatever it really was and alter it

Comment: @ohadsc - Do you think so ? It seems to me that `Rows.Select` returns a pure `IEnumerable<string>` which is pure read only and could not be casted back to anything else that what it is. No... ?

Comment: I think neither of them could affect the records stored in CustomerRow because they are all value types or behave like such. Anyway, I am returning a ReadOnlyCollection just to remind that the way to change records is through the methods in CustomerRow.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you don't set `Name` (which is read-only, indeed), but you set the first list element contained in `Name`, which is `Name[0]`, and there's no reason why you could not do that since `List<string>` is an object type which allows to set elements.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I will also study your suggestion above to use return Rows.Select(row => row.name); Especially this "=>" thing. Could you tell me what is this called?

Comment: I strongly encourage you to do so. It's called "lambda expression". Once you make the first step towards it and get the idea, a whole new world of possibilities appears to you and there's really a "before" and an "after" in how you develop.

Comment: So it seems. It's one line of code against six in this case. But I imagine OrderBy can save a lot more effort. I should have looked into it earlier. Thanks again.